# Pass Data from One Page to the other Page using Messaging Center

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am trying to pass data from one page to the other page using Messaging Center but it seems not to me working.

What I have tried:

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        async private void isClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MessagingCenter.Send<Page, string>(this, "Hi", "Data Sent");

            await Navigation.PushAsync(new FirstPage());
        }
    }
```

This is a Send from a first page named (MainPage) after the send I navigate to the other Page called FirstPage where I want to retrieve / subscribe to the message

On the first page I have this code:

```
   public partial class FirstPage : ContentPage
    {
        public FirstPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            ReceiveMessage();
        }

        public void ReceiveMessage()
        {
            MessagingCenter.Subscribe<Page, string>(this, "Hi", (sender, values) =>
            {
                lblLabel.Text = values;
            });
        }
    }
```

This does not seem to be working.. What could be the issue.

Comment: you are sending the message **before** the 2nd page is created, so by the time that `Subscribe` executes the message is already gone.  In this particular case it would be much easier to just pass the data to the 2nd page using it's constructor

Comment: Is there a way i can create the second page and make this work without passing the data through the 2nd page constructor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to subscribe **before** you send.  Messages are not queued, they are delivered immediately then disappear.  It would be much easier to just pass the data via the constructor, but if you insist on using `MessagingCenter`

1. create the page

   ```
   var page = new FirstPage();
   ```
2. subscribe to the message

   you are already doing this in the `FirstPage` constructor
3. send the message

   ```
    MessagingCenter.Send<Page, string>(this, "Hi", "Data Sent");
   ```
4. navigate to the page

   ```
    await Navigation.PushAsync(page);
   ```